# How do I remove punctuation from an array made by tokenizing a text file and return a new array with only words (no punctuation)?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

It's for a Computer Science project and we have to separate a text file, get rid of punctuation and upper-case letters then count the amount of times a word displays using sys.argv.  The format for the code our professor wants us to use is-

```
cleanToken = ""
for i in range(0,len(token),1):
     if (???):  #test token[i] to see if it is a letter
         cleanToken = cleanToken + token[i]
```

But that always pops up with an error message. Anyone know how to fix the error message?

Comment: Please post a sample token, and a list of things you consider punctuation

Answer (score 0):

`str.isalpha` tells you if a character lies in `a-z, A-Z`. Thus, you could use that in a filter expresion, to filter out the non-characters (i.e. punctuation). Once you've filtered, you just ned to join it into a string with `''.join(...)`:

```
>>> token = 'asdf-,asdf'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, token))
'asdfasdf'
```

Comment: Okay thank you, i still need to have the items of the list seperated in order to test how many times they occur.  Is there also a filter that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

For only lower-case letters, you can test against `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

...
for i in range(len(token)): # note that start=0 and step=1 are range's defaults
    if token[i] in ascii_lowercase:
        ...
```